# match variable string at end of field with awk

Tags: regex, awk

Yet again my unfamiliarity with AWK lets me down, I can't figure out how to match a variable at the end of a line?

This would be fairly trivial with `grep` etc, but I'm interested in matching integers at the end of a string in a specific field of a tsv, and all the posts suggest (and I believe it to be the case!) that awk is the way to go.

If I want to just match a single one explicity, that's easy:

Here's my example file:

```
PVClopT_11  PAU_02102   PAU_02064   1pqx    1pqx_A  37.4    13  0.00035 31.4    >1pqx_A Conserved hypothetical protein; ZR18,structure, autostructure,spins,autoassign, northeast structural genomics consortium; NMR {Staphylococcus aureus subsp} SCOP: d.267.1.1 PDB: 2ffm_A 2m6q_A 2m8w_A   No DOI found.
PVCpnf_18   PAK_3526    PAK_03186   3fxq    3fxq_A  99.7    2.7e-21 7e-26   122.2   >3fxq_A LYSR type regulator of TSAMBCD; transcriptional regulator, LTTR, TSAR, WHTH, DNA- transcription, transcription regulation; 1.85A {Comamonas testosteroni} PDB: 3fxr_A* 3fxu_A* 3fzj_A 3n6t_A 3n6u_A*    10.1111/j.1365-2958.2010.07043.x
PVCunit1_19 PAU_02807   PAU_02793   3kx6    3kx6_A  19.7    45  0.0012  31.3    >3kx6_A Fructose-bisphosphate aldolase; ssgcid, NIH, niaid, SBRI, UW, emerald biostructures, glycolysis, lyase, STRU genomics; HET: CIT; 2.10A {Babesia bovis}  No DOI found.
PVClumt_17  PAU_02231   PAU_02190   3lfh    3lfh_A  39.7    12  0.0003  28.9    >3lfh_A Manxa, phosphotransferase system, mannose/fructose-speci component IIA; PTS; 1.80A {Thermoanaerobacter tengcongensis}   No DOI found.
PVCcif_11   plu2521 PLT_02558   3h2t    3h2t_A  96.6    2.6e-05 6.7e-10 79.0    >3h2t_A Baseplate structural protein GP6; viral protein, virion; 3.20A {Enterobacteria phage T4} PDB: 3h3w_A 3h3y_A 10.1016/j.str.2009.04.005
PVCpnf_16   PAU_03338   PAU_03377   5jbr    5jbr_A  29.2    22  0.00058 23.9    >5jbr_A Uncharacterized protein BCAV_2135; structural genomics, PSI-biology, midwest center for structu genomics, MCSG, unknown function; 1.65A {Beutenbergia cavernae} No DOI found.
PVCunit1_17 PAK_2892    PAK_02622   1cii    1cii_A  63.2    2.7 6.9e-05 41.7    >1cii_A Colicin IA; bacteriocin, ION channel formation, transmembrane protein; 3.00A {Escherichia coli} SCOP: f.1.1.1 h.4.3.1   10.1038/385461a0
PVCunit1_11 PAK_2886    PAK_02616   3h2t    3h2t_A  96.6    1.9e-05 4.9e-10 79.9    >3h2t_A Baseplate structural protein GP6; viral protein, virion; 3.20A {Enterobacteria phage T4} PDB: 3h3w_A 3h3y_A 10.1016/j.str.2009.04.005
PVCpnf_11   PAU_03343   PAU_03382   3h2t    3h2t_A  97.4    4.4e-07 1.2e-11 89.7    >3h2t_A Baseplate structural protein GP6; viral protein, virion; 3.20A {Enterobacteria phage T4} PDB: 3h3w_A 3h3y_A 10.1016/j.str.2009.04.005
PVCunit1_5  afp5    PAU_02779   4tv4    4tv4_A  63.6    2.6 6.7e-05 30.5    >4tv4_A Uncharacterized protein; unknown function, ssgcid, virulence, structural genomics; 2.10A {Burkholderia pseudomallei}    No DOI found.
```

And I can pull out all the lines which have a "_11" at the end of the first column by running the following on the commandline:

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /_11$/) { print } }' 02052017_HHresults_sorted.tsv
```

I want to enclose this in a loop to cover all integers from 1 - 5 (for instance), but I'm having trouble passing a variable in to the text match.

I expect it should be something like the following, but `$i$` seems like its probably incorrect and by google-fu failed me:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ for (i=1;i<=5;i++){ if ($1 ~ /_$i$/) { print } } }' 02052017_HHresults_sorted.tsv
```

There may be other issues I haven't spotted with that awk command too, as I say, I'm not very awk-savvy.

***EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION***

I want to *separate out* all the matches, so can't use a character class. i.e. I want all the lines ending in "_1" in one file, then all the ones ending in "_2" in another, and so on (hence the loop).

Comment: You 100% do **not** need a loop to do what you say in your last paragraph but your requirements aren't clear - do you **really** only want to get the lines where $1 ends in 1-5 or do you want to get ALL lines output to separate files based on EVERY number that $1 ends in?

Comment: I disagree, I think with the clarification that I wanted to separate the rows in to files based on the string at the end of the first column (in this case numerically), the question was suitably clear. I concede it needed that clarification, as I was writing I obviously got a bit blind to the problem and thought it was more apparent than it was. A loop may not be *needed*, but my awk is only basic so yhis works for my needs. @Barmar was able to see the problem. And yes, I did want it based on every number $1 ends in, but its functionally the same problem in my case (max num is only 30).

Comment: That's just silly though. The right solution is so much simpler than looping through some hard-coded values looking for matches.... see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44682435/1745001.

Comment: There may also be situations where i only want the groups belonging to a spcific integer, so passing the loop iterator as a parameter suits my needs. This is only for a rough, hacky script that I will be the only one using.

Comment: Even so a loop is still just adding completely unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put variables inside `//`. Use string concatenation, which is done by simply putting the strings adjacent to each other in `awk`. You don't need to use a regexp literal when you use the `~` operator, it always treats the second argument as a regexp.

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { 
        if ( $1 ~ ("_" i "$") ) { print; break; }
     }' 02052017_HHresults_sorted.tsv
```

Comment: Ah neat! This looks promising. This approach would also presumably work if passing a shell variable in? So instead of the awk loop, I might have something like `awk -v iter="$shellvar" '{ $1 ~ "_" iter "$"}'`?

Comment: Yes, or you can do `for (i = 1; i < iter; i++)`

Comment: You can concatenate `i` to the output filename as well, e.g. `print > "filename_" i`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're thinking about this all wrong and what you really need is just (with GNU awk for gensub()):

```
awk '{ print > ("out" gensub(/.*_/,"",1,$1)) }' 02052017_HHresults_sorted.tsv
```

or with any awk:

```
awk '{ n=$1; sub(/.*_/,"",n); print > ("out" n) }' 02052017_HHresults_sorted.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop, use regex character class `[..]`:

```
awk 'match($1,/_([1-5])$/,a){ print >> a[1]".txt" }' 02052017_HHresults_sorted.tsv
```

Comment: he said `1 to 5` is just an example, he may want to match numbers with more than 1 digit.

Comment: Like `_11$` in his first example.

Comment: @Barmar, so he should elaborate the exact conditon. Now, this *to cover all integers from 1 - 5* is the only conditon

Comment: Actually I should probably have put this in the OP, for each integer (lets say I get 10 matches per integer) I want to separate out all of these in to sub-files, which I was going to do for each iteration of the loop. I don't want _all_ the matches at once.

My bad, wasn't as clear as I thought.

Comment: Yep just did as you were writing :)

Comment: @Barmar, don't bother with that. Go with your own solution. I have no joy to debate with you

Comment: @JoeHealey, besides, you **can** use a character class, see my update